# Visual studio tab keeps moving to the left

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I must have pressed a certain key combination, as the active tab keeps moving to be the far left. It doesn't matter which project the tab is for, it moves to the far left.

I have restarted Visual Studio and the machine, but it is still happening.

Anyone else come across this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to untick sorting here:

Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well > Sorting: Most recently used.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I kept moving tabs to be next to each other and when I would click off the moved tab it would jump back to where it was.  Tried the above solution, but it was already unticked.  Then I realized what it was.  Mine was sorting by alphabetical order.  So my solution was to untick the following:

Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well > Sorting: Alphabetically